# What is the expected value of the random variable Y defined below?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be discrete uniform on $\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$.  Let $Y$ be discrete uniform on $\{1,2,\ldots ,X\}$.  In other words, we choose uniformly from $\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$ and then depending on our choice $X$ we choose uniformly from  $\{1,2,\ldots ,X\}$.  Conditioning on the value of X,   I have

$P(Y = k) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=k}^{n} \frac{1}{j}$

So that

$E(Y) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n} \sum_{j=k}^{n} \frac{1}{j}$

It appears that the double sum above is equal to $\frac{n+3}{4}$ but I do not know how to show this.

Also, is there a way to derive the probability generating function for $Y$ from that of $X$ by composition or multiplication?

Comment: Swap the sums $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n} \sum\limits_{j=k}^{n} \frac{1}{j} =  \frac1n\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{j} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{j} k $ and the calculation is easy

Comment: @kimchilover  The first expression is the marginal probability not the conditional probability, and is constructed slightly peculiarly, but does look correct if you say $P(Y=k \mid X=j) = \frac1j$ when $1\le k \le j \le n$

Comment: @Henry.  OK  that's great.  Thanks.